# Internal SD card drive not returning/waking up after sleep/hibernate

Tags: windows, windows-10, macbook, boot-camp, sd-card

I have an internal SD card reader in my laptop. It contains a 32GB SD card that contains my research library. Information I use on a regular basis.

When the computer is woken up after being in sleep or hibernation the SD drive does not return.  No media removed chirp. No error reported. There is no evidence that it was ever there in the first place. Taking out the card and replacing it again has no effect. The SD card, and the card reader drive is ignored completely after wake up.

Rebooting will fix the problem, but this isn't really a fix as it defeats the point of being able to sleep the computer in the first place.

**System Details**: MacBook Pro running Windows 10 through boot camp. System runs Windows 10 almost exclusively. The SD card is internal. None of the USB ports and connect devices experience this problem. This has been an on going problem for months, through numerous updates so I do not think it is a update/driver issue.

Ideas? Suggestions? Anyone?

Comment: Look in device manager for the card reader then the 32gb card, double click it and see if there is a power management Tab, if there is be sure the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is Unchecked.

Comment: There is no power management tab is the listed for the drive. It did describe itself as a USB drive, so just to be extra sure I went in and disabled the "selective suspend" on all usb devices. This had no effect. While I was at it, I also checked for drive updates. There were none. And no old drives to revert to.

Comment: Sounds like a Windows 10 bug then.

Comment: This issue has apparently been around for more than two years. Both apple and microsoft acknowledge it as an issue although neither has bothered to address it. A discussion on the topic at the apple discussion board can be found at the following link: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5408471?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I have discovered a workaround - Lock the laptop first. From the lock screen, hibernate the laptop. When you turn the computer on again and login the drive should return as well.

Comment: I can confirm codingCat's workaround just worked with me on Win7 64bits, was having the same issue as OP, except I have a regular Windows laptop, not a Macbook

Comment: @Rodrigo, doesn't work in my case :(

Comment: @Sanu_012 after dealing with this issue for a number of years I think I have discovered the cause. USB devices tend to drop out when they are under powered. I ran into this issue quite often with the SD slot and the USB ports on the Macbook. The SD card slot on your laptop may not get power back from the laptop until after windows has recovered from hibernate mode. You may want to look into the advanced power settings for your machine, and check the forums for you manufacture. Someone may have found a fix to power up the port faster, to force windows to wait longer for to try again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the SD-Card in Device Manager. Then in the "view" menu select devices by connection. Click on properties of "Apple SD Card Reader" (which is the parent of "Apple SD Card Reader USB Device"). Then in the Power-Management tab uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power". Then do a restart.
2. This method will successfully reactivate the "card reader" or the "thunderbolt-ethernet-adapter" after hibernation without having to lock the screen.
3. **When the computer is woken up after being in sleep mode, you need to put it into hibernation. After coming out of hibernation all your devices will be there again.** This is a little bit cumbersome, but this workaround will save you from restarting your computer.