# Why does the attached SD card often not show up after sleep?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, sd-card, windows-10-v1709

I have a low end Windows 10 PC that I use to read PDFs and such stuffs. It has Intel Celeron processor with 4GB DDR3 RAM. I have inserted a Micro SD card (128GB) where I keep all the stuffs installed.

Since some days, I am facing this strange problem. When I put my PC to sleep and come back later to wake it up, I can't access anything that is stored on this memory card `(D:\)`. If I try opening an app that is installed in this drive, it just won't open. This happens very, very often, if not always.

When I navigate to **This PC**, I find that the card is simply not detected. Restarting the PC, however, solves this issue.

I searched about this problem in this forum and came across this: [Internal SD Card Drive not Returning/Waking up after Sleep/Hibernate](https://superuser.com/questions/1065513/internal-sd-card-drive-not-returning-waking-up-after-sleep-hibernate)

The above question was raised for an Apple product, and there is no accepted answer for it yet. Can anyone help me in this regard?

**EDIT:** So, after days of experimentation, I saw that *the problem* doesn't occur if I put my PC to sleep without opening any applications. But, as soon as I open an application, for example: the Opera Browser or the Adobe reader, and put it to sleep, then after waking up, the problem still persists.

I have tried hibernating as well, and it was strange that it behaved exactly the same way as is done after waking up from sleep mode. However, sleep and hibernation are two quite different in nature - sleep stores everything in RAM, while hibernation keeps everything in hard disk.
But I am confused why they're behaving similarly.

Can anyone shed light on this issue now, after having this much of details?

Screenshot as asked by @harrymc:

[image]

(The SanDisk is the brand of eMMC storage which is inbuilt)

**The solution that has worked for me:**

After troubleshooting and finally tracking all way down to confirm that the problem is actually with my SD card, I have been able to fix the issue as of now.

The first thing that I noticed is that the SD card was not bought much time ago (only 10 months old). So, I thought that the problem must lie with the software of the card rather than some hardware.

I copied all the files that were in the card to another PC using a USB card reader as the card was not being recognised in my phone to backup via USB cable. This again confirmed that the problem must lie with the software rather than hardware of the card, since it was being recognised in my PC but not in phones.

After backing up the data, I went on the format it. It was in exFAT mode by default. I changed it to NTFS and formatted quickly. Then I copied all my data back to my card and inserted into the PC and tried to reproduce the problem that happened earlier. I have tried twice till now, but the PC has been waking up normally ever since.

So, Yeah, the problem lied with the SD card, but has been fixed as of now. Thank you everyone who lent me a helping hand, especially harrymc :)

Comment: There are "solutions" mentioned in your the post you linked to. One such solution was to lock the PC and then put it to sleep/hibernate. Press Win+L as the shortcut key for lock screen, and then use the power controls from there. Does this help?

Comment: It could be a sign of the SD card controller failing and becoming unresponsive after some time and disconnecting from the card reader. A reboot would cycle the USB controller and hence the SD card interface. Have you tried a different card or different card reader?

Comment: Hello @JimDiroffII, I haven't tried that yet. I guess there must be some other way.

Comment: @Mokubai, I have just updated the Realtek USB 2.0 card reader driver. Will that solve this issue? Btw, I haven't tried a different card. Also, I don't need to use another card reader since I already have an inbuilt micro sd card reader that requires no adapter at all.

Comment: It depends if the card reader is the problem, and if the problem is with the driver rather than the hardware. If it is the card reader hardware then no. If it is the card itself then no. If the driver knows to reset the controller under certain circumstances then maybe, but allowing a driver to randomly disconnect a storage device the operating system is using is dangerous and I doubt it would.

Comment: @Mokubai, so how do you think this problem can be fixed?

Comment: I already asked: Have you tried a different card or different card reader?

Comment: No, I have done nothing of that sort yet. Will do if it persists for long and will also update the question accordingly.

Comment: I have, in the depths of history, heard of cards that simply do not "wake" fast enough and so cause these kinds of problems. Historically I *think* they were certain Samsung SD cards but others may have been implicated as well. If your card is old I would definitely recommend replacing it.

Comment: @Mokubai, Mine is also samsung micro SD card. It's around one and half years old. Btw, I have not been able to replicate the problem again since I upgraded the driver. Let's hope for the best :)

Comment: @JimDiroffII, I tried the method you suggested. But, there is no option to hibernate. I could see only 'Shut Down', 'Lock', 'Restart'. Tried enabling Hibernate option in power setting, the option doesn't seem to be there at all.

Comment: What is the exact model of the card reader?

Comment: Hello @harrymc, that is a built in micro sd card reader. How do I find out its model?

Comment: Find the device in Device Manager and report on its name. If not exact, right-click the device, Properties, Details tab, and report on the value(s) under "Hardware IDs" (or screenshot).

Comment: @harrymc, sorry for being late, the internet was extremely slow. The hardware ID shows these values: **USBSTOR\GenDisk**, **Gendisk**

Comment: That's all, are there are more values for Hardware IDs? Add a screenshot if there are many lines.

Comment: If your SD card reader is a usb hub or thumbdrive sized device, unplug the device and plug it back into another usb port. Then insert the SD card.

If your SD card reader is built in I do not know why it is failing to read your SD card

Comment: Hello @harrymc, yeah, that is all I can find under hardware IDs. I will add a screenshot for ur considerstion.

Comment: In device Properties, could you take a screenshot of the Driver tab. If the button of "Roll Back Driver" is enabled, try it and take a screenshot if the details change and try sleep again, before and after reboot. Try also to run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Hello @harrymc, the option of "Roll Back Driver" is greyed out, and hence unclickable. Should I still run *sfc \scannow*?

Comment: Yes, please do.

Comment: Hello @harrymc, I ran the command but the result was: `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`

Is there still some hope left?

Comment: I don't really have a clue as to the problem. Gendisk USB does not seem to have a driver from the manufacturer. You might try the heavy procedure of [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), but I'm really shooting in the dark. Mind your backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gendisk USB does not have a driver from the manufacturer,
so the generic driver from Windows is used.

To see if the problem is with some installed application,
try it while booting in Safe mode.
To locate the problematic application, you may use the free tool
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns),
turning off startup entries in bunches, drilling down to the problem startup
program.

If the problem is with the card itself, you might try formatting it again.
Use non-quick formatting, to ensure that all sectors have been rewritten.

If the problem is with Windows, you might try the heavy procedure of
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

If nothing helps, then I would guess that the problem is some hardware
incompatibility that has developed in the reader or disk.

The first test in this case is to try another SD card.
If it works better, then the first card is perhaps nearing its
end-of-life. Copy all files to the new card and only keep the old one
as frozen backup.

Comment: Since last some days, I have no been sleeping my PC, but when I tried sleep mode today and woke it up while an application was still running in the background, it didn't freeze. I think the issue has resolved on its own. Will keep updating the question if any recent development happens.

Comment: If you noticed from my answer, I don't really think that running applications can cause this problem, unless one application is locking the card and not releasing it after sleep. This then depends on analyzing which is the application that causes the problem.

Comment: I just woke it up from a 3 hour sleep, and it behaved the same way again. It froze.

Comment: Does it also happen with other cards?

Comment: Can I use autoruns to figure out which is the problematic application?

Comment: Never checked with other cards. I have all the installed applications on that particular sd card. Removing it will mean that I have to reinstall it again in the new card. An application like the opera browser or adobe reader.

Comment: This Autoruns for Windows seems too complicated. I failed following it till the end.

Comment: For Autoruns uncheck items to turn off and check again to enable. A reboot is required. I think it's worthwhile trying a new empty card, and if it works correctly then copy everything to it, perhaps by using a disk cloning product.

Comment: I have inserted my 32gigs sd card that was in my phone and put pc to sleep some time ago with a PDF reader running in the background. I hope, I get some good news. Btw, will reformatting the 128 gigs SD card that was giving error to NTFS solve the problem?

Comment: A positive update. I haven't been facing this problem with another card. What should I do now?

Comment: SD cards can go bad. If the card is just one partition, then copy all files to the new one and keep the old one as backup.

Comment: Can I make partitions in SD cards as well? I didn't know about that. What's the benefit of partitioning the card as I have still around 70 GB free space in it? Can I make two partitions and move all the files to that new partition and format the older partition to ntfs? Will that work?

Comment: And why come that sd card work smooth in my phone? I mean, if the problem is with sd card, shouldn't it face problems in phone as well?

Comment: There is no benefit from partitioning an SD card, some people do, especially on Linux. There is no explanation why a card would work on one reader and not on another, for example if one reader became a bit mis-calibrated, but it happens.

Comment: Actually, I just saw the date when I ordered this 128 GB sd card. It was delivered to me on 27th December, 2019. It's not even a year old and also not working properly. That's what we can expect from Chinese brands, I guess.

Comment: Yes, that explains something.

Comment: Hello @harrymc, thank you so much for following up with the question till this time. Accept my bounty as a token of appreciation :) Blessings from India <3

Comment: Thanks and return blessings from Europe.

Comment: Please update this answer and add a note about my SD card being at fault giving reference to all the comments received from me on this answer of yours. I will accept it as correct afterwards :)

Comment: No problem - done.

Comment: Thank you, done.

Comment: Hey @harrymc, the problem has been solved. See the updated question to know about it :)

Comment: I would guess that the magnetism applied in the factory was fading, so that formatting it again fixed the problem. If this happens again, it might mean that the card cannot hold its magnetism for long.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the problem is still coming up after you updated the SD card reader's driver. (According to your comment "@Mokubai, Mine is also samsung micro SD card. It's around one and half years old. Btw, I have not been able to replicate the problem again since I upgraded the driver. Let's hope for the best :)")

I would suggest restarting Windows File Explorer whenever this problem arises. From reading the comments on your question it doesn't seem to be a hardware issue, and I have had similar issues in the past that were resolved with a simple restart of Windows File Explorer.

The specific problem you're having sounds much more general than a specific hardware failure.

Comment: how do I restart WFE? the computer freezes after waking up from sleep after 10-15 secs.

Comment: Btw, thank you for the help :)

Comment: Press the windows key + r and open the "run" window. From there, type "taskmgr". After that, look under the "Processes" tab, and WFE should be somewhere in that list. You might have to look a little bit, but it will be there. Once you find it, left click it to highlight it. Then at the bottom of the Task Manager window you'll see the option to Restart

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a built-in SD card reader?
An external one could be simply unplugged and plugged back in.

Your problem could be power management related.
Search your device in device management and go through the list of properties.

There could be an entry with regards to the ability of switching power off. Try to vary this entry and test if the problem still persists.

Comment: Yes, the problem persists even after switching that off.

Comment: Btw, thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with a Dell XPS13-9380 laptop running Windows 11. It does not recognize the built-in microSD card after waking from sleep. However, I can rectify this by opening device manager, right-clicking any key, and invoking 'Scan for hardware changes.'

This can also be accomplished from an elevated prompt or batch file shortcut set to run with administrative privileges:

```
pnputil /scan-devices
```